# jQuery opening PDF in tab - additional tabs are opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

I am using jQuery to open a PDF in a new window or tab.  For the most part, it works.  I can click the link, and the PDF opens in a new tab.

The problem occurs when I open another PDF.

The new PDF will open, along with the previous PDF.  By the time I get to the 5th PDF, there will be 4 additional tabs from the PDFs that I previously opened.

I am working with datatables.  I click a link that contains data-attributes, which then opens a modal.  From inside the modal is where I'll have another click event that will then open the PDF:

```
$('#resultsTable').on('click', 'tr > td > a.uploadDocs', function(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#editForm input, select').val(''); // <- clear previous values

  var editbooking = $(this).attr('data-editbooking');   
  var editpartnercode = $(this).attr('data-editpartnercode');   

  // open PDF click event
  // takes vars editbooking and editpartner to build path and filename
  $('#downloadPDF').on('click', function()
  {
    var pdf = '../PartnerUploads/' + editpartnercode + '/' + editbooking + ".pdf";
    $.get(pdf)
    .done(function() 
    {
      window.open(pdf); 
    }).fail(function(textStatus)
    {
      if(textStatus.status == 404)
      {
        return false;
      }
    });
    // *** edit ***
    $('#downloadPDF').off('click');
  });
});
```

All of the above works as far as navigating to the directory, and then opening the file.  But it should not open all of the files that were previously opened.

How can I find why additional tabs are being opened when opening a PDF?

Comment: You have nested eventListeners in `$('#resultsTable').on('click'...)` meaning that everytime you press it, you will create a new `$('#downloadPDF').on('click'...)` event. You can use `$('#downloadPDF').off('click')` to remove the second event every time.

Comment: @Alex - I attempted your suggestion, but now the PDF doesn't open at all.

Comment: Are you adding it after `$('#downloadPDF').on(...)` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you have nested event binding.

Every time you will click on `#resultsTable`, you will create a new event for `#downloadPDF` every single time, resulting in exponentially growing the number of tabs you open.

Use [`$('#downloadPDF').off('click')`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) after `window.open(pdf);` and one inside `fail(function(textStatus)`.

---

**Solution:**

```
$('#resultsTable').on('click', 'tr > td > a.uploadDocs', function(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#editForm input, select').val(''); // <- clear previous values

  var editbooking = $(this).attr('data-editbooking');   
  var editpartnercode = $(this).attr('data-editpartnercode');   

  // open PDF click event
  // takes vars editbooking and editpartner to build path and filename
  $('#downloadPDF').on('click', function()
  {
    var pdf = '../PartnerUploads/' + editpartnercode + '/' + editbooking + ".pdf";
    $.get(pdf)
    .done(function() 
    {
      window.open(pdf); 
      $('#downloadPDF').off('click');
    }).fail(function(textStatus)
    {
      if(textStatus.status == 404)
      {
        return false;
      }
      $('#downloadPDF').off('click');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Should the $('#downloadPDF').off('click') look exactly like the $('#downloadPDF').on('click') event?

Comment: Actually. You need to use `$('#downloadPDF').off('click');` after `window.open(pdf);` and after your `fail` case. This will remove the event after you successfully get your data.

Comment: Got it!  Thank you, sir.  That's what I was looking for.

Comment: No problem! Happy to help :)